# how to get the sum of 2 array with the same id in a collection

Tags: php, laravel

i have an array of collections with some same occurrences like below :

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => Collection {#926 ▶}
  1 => Collection {#926 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#1045 ▶}
  3 => Collection {#1045 ▶}
  4 => Collection {#1156 ▶}
  5 => Collection {#1156 ▶}
]
```

now what i want to do is to is to get the sum of those who repeated like `926` so i would have `2` prices to sum because `926` occurred `2` times . how can i achieve that thanks !

Comment: Can you elaborate in details with example?

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Answer (score 3):

Use this approach:

```
// sum same keys in an array
$sum = array_sum(array_column($yourarray, 'your key/index'));
```

Comment: actually i dont have the keys before the output .

Comment: @Farshad what do you mean you dont have key before output?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do like this.

```
$array = [
    '0' => array( 
        'id' => 926, 
        'total' => 90, 
    ),
    '1' => array( 
        'id' => 926, 
        'total' => 10, 
    ),
    '2' => array( 
        'id' => 927, 
        'total' => 101, 
    ),
    '3' => array( 
        'id' => 928, 
        'total' => 101, 
    ),
];
$result = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $id = $v['id'];
    $result[$id][] = $v['total'];
}

$new = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $new[] = array('id' => $key, 'total' => array_sum($value));
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 926
            [total] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 927
            [total] => 101
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 928
            [total] => 101
        )

)
```